# AMD Module Shaping: How to load only one JS function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

Many JavaScript libraries have a Builder tool that will allow you to "shape" what features of the library you depend on, both in terms of download bandwidth cost to the client and in terms of isolating functionality you actually need.

For example, I like many things in sugar.js, but I simply don't need or want katakana and hiragana character set handling.  As the most trivial example, I want to be able to "shape" sugar.js to only export string.isBlank().

Is there a tool available to do this for me?  Is there any ongoing effort by the EcmaScript committee to do something like this in a future version of JavaScript?  Do any higher-level languages like TypeScript and CoffeeScript, offer hidden support for such "shaping"?  I can do such "shaping" in C# for .NET DLLs via [monolinker](http://www.mono-project.com/Linker).

Basically, it looks to me like AMD handles the Loader aspect of a modern compiler, but does not handle the Linker aspect.  Builders for [jquery](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and [dojo](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/) only work for a specific module, and aren't true Linkers, just Builders.

**UPDATE:** [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) is a compiler that takes JavaScript as input and produces JavaScript as output.  The [Advanced Compilation and Externs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#removal) documentation suggests there is an API call to do this:

> If putting together these export statements seems too tedious, you can use a function to do the exporting for you. See the Closure Library functions [goog.exportSymbol()](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.html#goog.exportSymbol) and [goog.exportProperty()](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.html#goog.exportProperty) for examples of exporting functions.

However, this seems pretty convoluted, and makes me directly dependent on Google Closure Compiler.  At this point, I am looking for info about future standards from the EcmaScript Committee, with regards to CommonJS, and for any wisdom from people who have thought about this problem and attempted to tackle it.  Especially from fellow TypeScript developers; I don't want to have to create declare files in TypeScript for sugar.js, then use Google Closure Compiler against my TypeScript compiler output.  It just sounds impossibly complex and hard to debug.

Comment: That's a good question. I don't think any tool can do this automatically. JavaScript being so flexible, it's not rare to see a function change at runtime or depending on the state of the application... It may be hard to really extract a function easily. So, I can assure you that right now, you can't use a Linker to only get `$.each` out of jQuery if the original authors didn't built-in the option. May this come? Maybe, but I don't saw it in the near future. (maybe al the work done on static analytics tools right now will help going this way)

Comment: That is what I suspected.  I have seen Allen Wirfs-Brock and Nikolai Tillman of MS Research give examples where a 6 line JS code block in isolation could have dozen different meanings depending on what the variables are typed as at *time of interpretation*.  Hence, why I also asked about TypeScript and other high-level langauges that support optional typing.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is Nikolai's example, taken from his SPUR talk at VMIL 2010 (http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~design/vmil/2010/slides/p03-tillmann-slides.pdf)
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
if (i == 990) {
sum += " Hello World "
}
sum += 1
}
print(sum)

Comment: Just to note that d.ts. files for sugar have already been created for you: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/sugar

Comment: @JcFx Yes, sugar.js also has its own builder.  Ideally, I would use sugar.d.ts and then let a linker take care of ignoring the stuff I don't use.

Comment: if you want string.isBlank(), to to the page and type "".isBlank into firebug or chrome devtools and copy the source. run the source in action. if you get a ref error, repeat the process of typing names into the console until all depends are collected. you can automate this using try/catch.  some libs like to do things like x.getTags=document.all?..., which means that different pieces are different in different browsers, and so it might not be x-browser code. Still, i have used this a lot over the years and it works more often than not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing built into Javascript to do this "shaping", and really what you want is a compiler anyway, since roughly one of the roles it serves is to automate "shaping" at many levels (not just with methods).

The Closure Compiler is mature and open source (JQuery is actually minified using the Closure Compiler). So if you're going to begin annotating your JS code for a compiler, it might as well be this one.

There a huge number of side benefits of using a compiler, btw. They will reduce your file sizes (and thus interpretation/run time) a great deal more than simply shaping your included libraries. And while you're developing it will produce a lot of helpful messages to catch bugs early.